# the package XXX links to the native library YYY, but it conflicts with a previous package which links to YYY as well:package ZZZ

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a project depends on xxx(xxx have links to a native c library 'a'),and i want to introduce a new dependency yyy which also have links to 'a'(some library different version). when i run 'cargo update', it fait and logged 'failed to select a version for `xxx`....the package `xxx` links to the native library `a`, but it conflicts with a previous package which links to `a` as well:
package `yyy`'

i have read some document, and it seem practical to make the links global by add some code in cargo.toml,and build.rs, but i not sure how to do and can two different dependency have the same links?

```
error: failed to select a version for `parity-rocksdb-sys`.
    ... required by package `parity-rocksdb v0.5.0`
    ... which is depended on by `kvdb-rocksdb v0.1.4`
    ... which is depended on by `storage v0.0.1 (/Users/chenrui/Desktop/blockchain/WendingWorkStation/ipfs/filesys-rust/runtime/storage)`
    ... which is depended on by `beacon v0.0.1 (/Users/chenrui/Desktop/blockchain/WendingWorkStation/ipfs/filesys-rust/chain/beacon)`
    ... which is depended on by `client v0.1.0 (/Users/chenrui/Desktop/blockchain/WendingWorkStation/ipfs/filesys-rust/chain/client)`
    ... which is depended on by `alphanet v0.1.0 (/Users/chenrui/Desktop/blockchain/WendingWorkStation/ipfs/filesys-rust/chain/alphanet)`
    ... which is depended on by `devnet v0.1.0 (/Users/chenrui/Desktop/blockchain/WendingWorkStation/ipfs/filesys-rust/chain/devnet)`
    ... which is depended on by `filesys v0.1.0 (/Users/chenrui/Desktop/blockchain/WendingWorkStation/ipfs/filesys-rust)`
versions that meet the requirements `^0.5` are: 0.5.5, 0.5.4, 0.5.3, 0.5.2, 0.5.1, 0.5.0

the package `parity-rocksdb-sys` links to the native library `rocksdb`, but it conflicts with a previous package which links to `rocksdb` as well:
package `librocksdb-sys v5.17.2`
    ... which is depended on by `rocksdb v0.12.0`
    ... which is depended on by `filecoin-proofs v0.1.0 (https://github.com/idotial/rust-fil-proofs.git#53676171)`
    ... which is depended on by `filesys v0.1.0 (/Users/chenrui/Desktop/blockchain/WendingWorkStation/ipfs/filesys-rust)`

failed to select a version for `parity-rocksdb-sys` which could resolve this conflict

fix this error, and finish cargo update
```

Comment: I new a example project in git https://github.com/idotial/testlinks.git , this project can show the problem more clearly.